# Creating a new directory inside Android internal memory and writing data to it

Tags: java, android, file

Most of the examples I have seen deal with external memory or show how to create a new directory inside internal memory but not how to write to it, I tried implementing my own code into it but can't seem to find the created file even though the directory has been created, here is the code that I have been trying to use:

```
public void fileCreate(Context context, String fileDir) throws Exception{

        File myNewDir = context.getDir(fileDir, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (!myNewDir.exists()){
            myNewDir.mkdirs();


            File testContnet = new File(myNewDir + "/hello_file.txt");
            String hello = "Hello world";
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(testContnet.toString(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(hello.getBytes());
            fos.close();

        }

    }
```

Now, when I call this function I use:

```
try {
      fileCreate(this, "testerDirectory");
     }catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

With no results. It is just for a small experiment I am doing so it is nothing too serious, but I still want to know about the proper way of creating a directory(in this case one called testerDirectory, and saving the file to it, I believe that my code is wrong but I do not have much experience with this to know exactly where to go. The Android documentation did show me how to create and save files although in this case I am trying to merge that example with that of creating a new directory and saving a file to it. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I know also that the file is not being written accordingly upon inspecting the contents of the directory by using the adb shell.

Comment: "I tried implementing my own code into it but can't seem to find the created file" -- please explain, **in detail**, how you are looking for it, considering that you do not have access to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) of Android devices with most tools.

Comment: @CommonsWare    Hello, I am little confused, if I run the code provided in the Android documentation to save a file to internal memory I can arrive at the file by means of the shell by running adb inside the terminal and then going into the package with the command run-as, at that point there would be a directory called files which has all the content that one would write in it. this is basically the same concept that I am trying to apply in here.

Comment: Sorry, I glossed over the last sentence of your question. My apologies.

Comment: no problem at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only writing a file to the directory if the directory does not already exist.

Move your work with `testContnet` to be outside of the `if` block:

```
public void fileCreate(Context context, String fileDir) throws Exception{

    File myNewDir = context.getDir(fileDir, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!myNewDir.exists()){
        myNewDir.mkdirs();
    }


    File testContnet = new File(myNewDir, "hello_file.txt");
    String hello = "Hello world";
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputstream(testContnet);
    fos.write(hello.getBytes());
    fos.flush();
    fos.getFD().sync();
    fos.close();
}
```

This way, you create the directory if it does not exist, but then create the file in either case. I also added `fos.flush()` and `fos.getFD().sync()`, to ensure all bytes get written to disk before you continue.

**UPDATE**: You were using `openFileOutput()`, which does not write to your desired directory. Moreover, it is unnecessary. Just create a `FileOutputStream` on your `File`.

Comment: Thank you for that, unfortunately, only the directory is created but file inside of it with the content is not. The permissions have been added to the manifest file as well btw, and I tried removing the app from the emulator and  installing it again. Still no result.

Comment: got it now! I misinterpreted the use of the openFileOutput() function, it is working as I need it now. Thank you for your time!